# Смена системы координат на полярную Python

Tags: python, tkinter, matplotlib

Помогите, пожалуйста, пытаюсь добавить кнопку смены системы координат с декартовой на полярную и наоборот, но ничего не работает, в чем может быть ошибка. Так же не появляется окно с параметрами. Заранее благодарю за помощь

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk

# Функция для вычисления координат точек на дельтоиде в полярных координатах
def deltoid(t, a):
    r = 2 * a * np.cos(t+.85) + a * np.cos(2 * t+.85)
    theta = t + np.pi/2
    return r, theta

# Функция для обновления параметров
def update_params():
    # Получаем значение параметра из текстового поля
    a = float(entry_a.get())

    # Обновляем параметры дельтоиды
    t = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 1000)
    r, theta = deltoid(t, a)
    r_max = np.max(r)
    r = r_max / 3.0
    r_inner = r_max - r
    theta_c = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 1000)
    circle_r = np.full_like(theta_c, r)
    circle.set_data([theta[0]], [r[0]])
    circle_deltoid.set_data(theta, np.full_like(theta, r_max))
    circle_inner.set_data(theta_c, np.full_like(theta_c, r_inner))
    radius_line.set_data([np.pi/2, np.pi/2 + np.pi/4], [r[0], r[0]])
    ax.set_ylim([0, r_max])
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

# Создаем окно приложения
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Deltoid")

# Создаем рамку для параметров
frame_params = tk.Frame(root)
frame_params.pack()

# Создаем текстовое поле для ввода параметра "a"
label_a = tk.Label(frame_params, text="a:")
label_a.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

entry_a = tk.Entry(frame_params, width=10)
entry_a.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
entry_a.insert(0, "2.0")

# Создаем кнопку "Update"
button_update = tk.Button(frame_params, text="Update", command=update_params)
button_update.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

# Создаем фигуру и оси для полярной системы координат
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 12), subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))

# Вводим параметры дельтоиды и примитива
a = 2.0

# Вычисляем координаты точек на дельтоиде
t = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 1000)
r, theta = deltoid(t, a)

# Преобразуем координаты из полярных в декартовы
x, y = r * np.cos(theta), r * np.sin(theta)

# Отображаем дельтоиду на графике
ax.plot(theta, r, color='blue')

# Создаем красный круг радиуса r
r_max = np.max(r)
r = r_max / 3.0
r_inner = r_max - r
theta_c = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 1000)
circle_r = np.full_like(theta_c, r)
circle = ax.plot([theta[0]], [r[0]], color='red')[0]

# Создаем окружность, описанную вокруг дельтоиды
circle_deltoid = ax.plot(theta, np.full_like(theta, r_max), color='green')[0]

# Создаем оранжевый круг радиуса r_inner
circle_inner = ax.plot(theta_c, np.full_like(theta_c, r_inner), color='orange', alpha=0.5)[0]

# Добавляем линию радиуса красного круга
radius_line = ax.plot([np.pi/2, np.pi/2 + np.pi/4], [r[0], r[0]], color='black')[0]

# Функция, которая будет вызываться на каждом кадре анимации
def animate(i):
    # Вычисляем координаты точки на дельтоиде в полярных координатах
    t_i = i / 50.0
    r_i, theta_i = deltoid(t_i, a)

    # Перемещаем красный круг по оранжевому кругу
    x_c, y_c = r_inner, theta_i

   # Перемещаем красный круг
    circle.set_data([theta_i], [r_i])

    # Обновляем линию радиуса красного круга
    radius_line.set_data([theta_i, theta_i + np.pi/4], [r_i, r_i])

    # Возвращаем примитивы, которые должны быть обновлены на этом кадре
    return circle, circle_deltoid, circle_inner, radius_line

# Создаем анимацию
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=1000, interval=1)

# Запускаем главный цикл приложения
root.mainloop()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Не понятно зачем вам tkinter, необходимые виджеты есть и в matplotlib https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/widgets_api.html. Если вы все-таки хотите использовать  ткинтер, то для этого есть встраивание https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html, а так у вас будут конфликтовать два основных цикла. И я так понимаю, вам надо создать две функции для отображения фигуры и переключаться между ними.